# Calculate shape orientation in Java (Image analysis)

Tags: java, image, geometry, shapes

I have an image such as this:

[image]

and I need to calculate the orientation of it. In this case the shape is pointing towards the top left of the screen. Accuracy isn't hugely important as long as 3 or 4 calculations average out to within 5 degrees or so of the actual orientation (it will be moving slightly).

Can anyone point me towards an algorithm to do this? I don't mind if the orientation is returned as a double or as a vector.

Comment: Do you always know what the shape should look like?  Do you know where the centre of rotation is?  Is the shape always the same size?

Comment: @PeterLang - seriously? You had to link the image in? I would qualify this as a successful troll.

Comment: No troll. It is a T shape, but I use colour thresholding to get the shape back. Obviously the edges aren't going to be perfect using this method so it returns a shape like above. Can we please try and keep it serious?

The centre of rotation is pretty much the centroid of the shape, and is always the same size (never varies by more than a few percent). The shape should be the same. The only time it changes is when the lighting varies too quickly for the camera to cope and we miss out some of the pixels. The above example is a "good" one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution in the end was to use a [Convex Hull Algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms), which finds the minimum number of points needed to enclose a shape with a bound.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is always T-shaped, you can simply get the furthest pair of pixels, then find the furthest pair from <strike>either</strike> both of those (the edges of the T), find which is further from the other two, draw a line from that one to the middle point of those two.

You can further refine it by then finding the base of the T by comparing the middle line with the edges of the base, and adjusting the angle and offset until it is actually in the middle.

Comment: But if I find the pair furthest from those it will just find them selves again? If we exclude these points from the search then it will just find the pixels next to them as the T isn't perfect so it is very likely asymmetrical.

Comment: This is the method that I use, but it does fail badly when the T changes shape due to lighting. This is beyond the scope of my original question, but any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

The definitive solution is impossible I guess, since requires image recognition. I would project the 2D image onto axis, i.e. obtain the width and height of the image and get direction vector from these values taking them as components.

Comment: That sounds like exactly what I need, but how do I "project" it?

Comment: How do you have image represented? Often it is in 2d array. Then just sum each row -- you will get a totals column, and also sum each column -- you well get a totals row. Having this row and column determine the ranges of presence. Depending of what value you have for white and colored pixels. Suppose you have `x` ranging from `x1` to `x2` and `y` from `y1` to `y2`. Then your vector is `{x2-x1, y2-y1}`. Also you need to know where is the beginning and where is the end. Probably you can determine this by location of "fat" part.

Answer (score 0):

First, a couple of assumptions:

1. The center and centroid are "close"
2. The descending bar of the T is longer than the cross-bar

First, determine the bounding rectangle of the image and find the points of the image that lie along this rectangle.  For points that lie along the line and are a certain distance from one another (say 5 pixels to pick a value) you'll need to only take 1 point from that cluster.  At the end of this you should have 3 points, i.e. a triangle.  The shortest side of the triangle should be the cross-bar (from assumption 2), i.e. find the two points closest to each other.  The line that is perpendicular to the line crossing those two points is then your orientation line, i.e. find the angle between it and the horizontal axis.

Answer (score 0):

I would try [morphological skeletonization](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/skeleton.htm) to simplify the image, followed by some straightforward algorithm to determine the orientation of the longer leg of the skeleton.

Comment: This looks fantastic. Certainly something I would be interested in trying.